# How to use environment variables in Java with Eclipse? (MAC OS X)

Tags: java, eclipse, bash

In .bash_profile I have listed many env variables as follows:

```
export JAVA_HOME=...
export PYTHON=... 
...
```

System.getenv() returns a list of env variables (e.g., SHELL, TMP_DIR) but not those listed in .bash_profile. Where these are coming from and how to get the ones in .bash_profile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want them in .bashrc instead of .bash_profile. See the INVOCATION section of the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for details of how and when certain init files are loaded.

Comment: Oh, that assumes that you're running eclipse from the bash session where you've exported the variables. If running from the desktop, you'll either have to create a custom script that exports them for you or else put the variables in /etc/environment, where you don't export them, just list them like "JAVA_HOME=...".

Comment: That's exactly what I ran into when I tried to create a quick launch icon in the tool bar on Linux, and writing a simple script to start Eclipse was the solution.

Comment: Oops, on MAC, it should be /etc/launchd.conf or ~/.launchd.conf instead of /etc/environment. For example: http://www.digitaledgesw.com/node/31

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse takes them from the run configuration.  menu Run->Run Configurations...

Select your app, switch to the arguments tab, and put your env variables down there, eg:

-Dname=value

Comment: Wait a sec!  That's System.getProperties(), not getenv().  Doh.

Comment: Adding the env under configuration worked. Thanks! 

Would be nice to do it programmatically too. Just tried System.getProperties() and it returns a lot of stuff but not the env listed in .bash_profile