# Using Java code to get env variable returns null in MacOS Catalina

Tags: java, macos, environment-variables, environment

I am using MacOs Catalina 10.15.7. I add an env variable "LOG_PATH" in .bash_profile. After that, I restart computer and run printenv. I can see that variable. So far so good.

I have a java code to get the value from that env variable:

```
 System.out.println("LOG PATH="+System.getenv("LOG_PATH"));
```

But it returns null.
How does that happen?

Comment: How do you run your Java program? You'd have to start it from a bash prompt to get any bash variables.

Comment: See if the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65597552/how-exactly-to-set-up-and-use-environment-variables-on-mac) works for you.

Comment: I am running java code from eclipse IDE

Comment: @David: and which one of the parent processes of the Eclipse IDE do you expect to interpret `.bash_profile`? If there's no bash anywhere in there, then that file means nothing. Read the question Alias Cartellano linked to, it has a detailed explanation of which files influence what.

Comment: @Joachim: I install Eclipse in macos and click on the icon to run Eclipse IDE. I dont know what is the parent process of Eclipse IDE. The .bash_profile that i modified is the one stays in /Users/david1234. (david1234 is my username). The link from Alias is for BigSur not Catalina.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669821/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-java-with-eclipse-mac-os-x/6669853#6669853. Try this one instead.